# ClickOnce application when run from start menu gets the URL it was originally downloaded from

Tags: clickonce

Our users run our ClickOnce [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application from the start menu / desktop shortcut. When the application starts each time we need to get the URL it was originally downloaded from. I tried using the ActivationUri, but this only works when it was run directly from the website setup.exe rather than the desktop / start menu shortcut:

```
string activationUri = "???";
try
{
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment == null)
    {
        activationUri = "currentDeployment is null";
    }
    else if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri == null)
    {
        activationUri = "deployment not null but uri is";
    }
    else if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri != null)
    {
        activationUri =
            System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    activationUri = ex.Message;
    //Error getting the URL so put question mark
}

MessageBox.Show(activationUri);
```

When run from the setup (from a website) I would get the URL, and every other time I would get "deployment not null but URI is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ApplicationDeployment.UpdateLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updatelocation.aspx) property. Unless you have configured a different update URL in the Project Properties -> Publish -> Updates -> Update Location in Visual Studio, it should return you the original deployment URL.

Comment: awesome.. I due to time constraints I put the writing to file solution in, but much prefer this option. Will try it out when I get a chance today.

Answer (score 8):

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

is not null if you activate the "**Allow URL Parameters to be passed to the application**" checkbox in the Publish Manifest options.

Otherwise use `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation`!

Answer (score 1):

I think all you can do is save the URI somewhere when the application downloads and runs the first time and then reference this value when the application runs offline.

Comment: I had that thought as well recently, was hoping for a more elegant solution, but I think this will do.